# replacement for clock app

Tags: android, clock, dock, nexus-one

the least thing i like on the nexus one is the useless app it runs when on the desktop dock.

I already wasted a good day searching for the 3 topics below and failed to find anything.

1. Is there any replacement for it already available?
2. Is there source code for the original one?
3. Is there documentation on how to replace them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Very Likely. Look in Android Market; I'm sure there's a desktop clock replacement app there.
2. Yes. look at [DeskClock.git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=summary).
3. Yes. look at [Intent.CATEGORY_DESK_DOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DESK_DOCK). If you create an activity with an `intent-filter` that contains this category it'll show up in the list of available apps (the 'chooser') when the phone is docked.